# For loop stopping prematurely

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve problem #299 - Train Swapping in website UVa Online judge. The code I have works fine for independent test cases. However, when I use the sample input they provide, my program omits one of the test cases, the last one to be more specific:

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {
  void problem(){
    Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numT =imput.nextInt();
    int numL, aux, swaps=0;
    int [] train = new int [50];

    for (int i =0; i<numT; i++) {
      numL = imput.nextInt();

      for (int m =0; m< numL; m++) {
        train[m]=imput.nextInt();
      }

      for (int j=0; j<numL; j++) {
        if (train[j]>train[j+1]) {
          for (int k =j; k<numL-1;k++) {
            aux = train[k];
            train[k]=train[k+1];
            train[k+1]=aux;
            swaps++;
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Optimal train swapping takes "+swaps+" swaps.");
      swaps = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Example Input:

```
3
3
1 3 2
4
4 3 2 1
2
2 1
```

Example Output:

```
Optimal train swapping takes 1 swaps.
Optimal train swapping takes 6 swaps.
Optimal train swapping takes 1 swaps.
```

My code prints until the second solution, then for some reason stops. I've tried to debug it and check what's going on step by step but it has driven me to a migraine point. Any insight is highly appreciated.

...
To be more precise it stops at the second **for** loop the third time around without taking anything into the array...and I don't know why!

Another thing I found out is that to solve this problem the number of swaps for the case of the middle is 6, therefore the bubble sort wont be useful here, since it makes over 10 swaps thus yielding a wrong output, this is a separate issue to the original one I presented however. I still haven't figure out why it stops the third time around the loop where I assign values to the array for the third time.
The input consists of:
first line is number of cases. 
this line enters the length of a train ex: 4
this line enters the number of the wagons ex: 2 4 3 1
the next following lines correspond to the following test cases whose structure is the same as the example.
They ask you to arrange the train and tell the number of swaps made to make the train in order.

Comment: What is Problem #299 - Train Swapping? Can you please describe what this program is supposed to do?

Comment: how do you provide the input to your program ?

Comment: If I run this program, I get exactly the output you show us, then the program terminates.  As near as I can tell, there is no bug.

Are you entering an end-of-line (enter/return) after each line of input?  How are you giving the input?

Comment: iam just copying the sample imput from the problem's website and entering completely.

Comment: Youre absolutely right, I submitted the solution and it worked like a charm, for some reason my compiler stops just before taking the input for the last case the one with a train whose cars in the order 2 1, this gave me a migraine yesterday whats going on here!